# Reading csv with errors using on_bad_lines not working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to use the relatively new option to pass a callable to the `on_bad_lines` argument while reading an unknown csv file, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
def foo(csv_file_data):
 badlines_list = []
 def badlines_collect(bad_line):
     badlines_list.append(bad_line)
     return None

 df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_file_data), engine="python", on_bad_lines=badlines_collect)
 # do something
 
 return df.to_csv(index=False), badlines_list
```

I'm testing the code with a file I know for certain has offending lines, but the `badlines_list` list is returned empty on each run.

I saw the PR about it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45146), and it seems like I'm using it correctly.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can someone please help me?

Note that I'm using the latest version of pandas (1.4.0).

Thanks!

Edit: added a screenshot of a local test that doesn't work for me

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I'm on 1.3.5, yet can't pass a callable for `on_bad_lines` even though  the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
 claim this should be possible since 1.3.0.

Comment: Anyway, according to the same docs, the callable passed for `on_bad_lines` should accept a list, not a string

Comment: I'm using pandas 1.4.0, and I tried using a type hint of ```(bad_line: list):``` as well as ```(bad_line: list) -> None:```. Both didn't work

Comment: Note: you are returning two items, the return code from `to_csv()` which is usually `None` followed by your `badlines_list`. I have tested similar code using Pandas 1.4.0 and the callable seems to work fine. In your case skipping over bad rows and creating a list of them

Comment: I can't figure what's not working for me... Added a screenshot of a test I've done, can you please help me understand what I'm missing? Thanks!